# android app with react native expo doesn't work in offline mode

Tags: android, react-native, expo, expo-sqlite

I've developed an android app with react native expo, this app depends on a static data where the database can be considered as a read only database where I've a (.db) file which contain  all the data and I need to read the data from the file and show it in in my app so I've followed expo-sqlite documentation on how to open a new SQLite database using an existing .db file you already have and it works correctly but only in online mode where in offline mode I can't get the data from the database.

I think the problem is that the expo-sqlite uploading the data on a server somewhere, so is there any thing to do inorder to make the database hosted locally

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please add enough info to your question to create a [mcve]: code, error messages, etc. See also [ask].

Comment: Expo-sqlite is definitely not uploading your data remotely, no one is hosting your DB for free. When you say it doesn't work in offline mode, what do you mean? How is offline mode defined? What error do you get?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: when I said "offline mode" I mean "when the device is not connected to the internet.